# Create a column based on multiple columns- in R

Tags: r

I am familiar with statistical packages including R but I kind of stopped working in R in between and recently started using it again.

I have simple questions and any help would be greatly appreciated it.

My question is: I want to create a variable by fulfilling in a condition based on multiple columns/variables. For instance, a new variable to code as "1" if there is no missing values in any one of the columns from 1 to 100 and to code as 0 if otherwise.

How could I possibly solve this in R or possible code suggestions?

Many thanks in advance.

Kind regards,
Mahesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example.

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, NA), b=c(6, 7, 8, NA, 9, 10, NA))
df$new.column <- ifelse(is.na(df$a) & is.na(df$b), 1, 0)
df
```

HTH!

Comment: MacOs, many thanks for your response. True, it works for two variables but I was wondering if there are about 300 variables. I was wondering of using [,1:300] not  listing each and every variable.

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this without an `ifelse`

```
df$new.column <- with(df, +(is.na(a) & is.na(b)))
```